# ignore field based on condition while marshalling

Tags: java, xml, marshalling

The following class needs to be marshalled to xml.

```
class A {
    @XmlElement
    private boolean readFlag;

    // ... and some other fields
}
```

However, the `readFlag` should **only** be in the returned xml, **under some conditions**. I can not use `@XmlTransient`, because that would always leave it out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: rephrased the question, and corrected some java syntax errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing you could do is use the `Boolean` wrapper class and set the value of the field to `null` if you don't want to have it marshalled - `null` fields are left out by default.

If you use EclipseLink/MOXy as JAXB implementation, you could also use its object graph feature, for a list of articles about that see [here](http://blog.bdoughan.com/search/label/Object%20Graphs).